# Instable kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I currently have a problem with an pod on my GCP (google cloud platform) cluster.
The pod's status change in this order :

1. The first time it is on "ERROR status",
2. Second time (automatic restart) it take "RUNNING status"
3. And the third time (automatic restart) it become "CrashLoopBackOff" and stay always
   on this last status.

When I run `kubectl describe  pod mypod -n mynamespace` I don't see any error just [image]

I have no idea about what can causes this weird behavior.

Any idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to answer your question. The first place to look for errors is in the pod logs (`kubectl logs ...`); do you see anything there? Update the question and let us know what you find. It would also help us if you can show us the Pod manifest.

Comment: Thank @larsks, I completely forgotten the logs command, I expect to have all details by "describe" command. So running logs command help to fix my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your pod is automatically restarted and transitions from the Running state to the CrashLoopBackOff state, it suggests that the pod is experiencing recurring failures or errors. As CrashLoopBackOff state is a way to prevent the system from continuously restarting a failing pod.

Use the `kubectl logs` to examine the logs of the pod and ensure that the pod has sufficient resources allocated to it.

Insufficient CPU or memory of the node can cause the application to crash repeatedly.

Comment: Thank @Siegfred V., I completely forgotten the logs command, I expect to have all details by "describe" command. So running logs command help me to fix my problem